# Facebook app for website

Tags: web, facebook-apps

**Help me.**.
I'm implementing a web application in my local server and after i will publish my application to download and can use every one.So I need to give a social experience to user with my web application(user can update his **fan pages** through my web application). So i created a facebook application. But I'm still in problem what is *site url* in application. This is not for my own web site. This is for all download users. Then how can I create a facebook application to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

With a facebook Canvas App, site url is where the actual application is hosted.

So, if your web application was fully functional at http://example.com/facebook, that would be the site URL.

I created a facebook app last year and it's a web based application that is wholly contained within my webserver, the site url points to it's landing page.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos.. But that web application doesn't have specific server. Becoz it's developing in localhost and then give to a user. So user download the application and install in a his server. so how to create a facebook app to use in this web application without any errors.

Comment: And can't we create a facebook application for web site which can use many web sites.

Comment: @Kalya Abbey I think I understand where you are going with this.  You have this app that you will be distributing, I could get this app from you and install it on my server and use it as a facebook app.  If that is the case, I would create the "finished" product and have it working as a facebook app in my enviroment (IE, have the site url set up to go to it etc..) so I can test the authentication etc...

Comment: Then, I would create a "how to" document for them to install it and what steps they need to get it up and running.  It almost sounds like you need something other than a facebook app by what you are trying to accomplish though.  Have you looked at the fbml ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make this application downloadable like wordpress framework so that others can host the application on their server and use it.

So probably best way is to have a admin section like in wordpress, user who download and implement you application on his or her server can provide their own application access token.

Insted of hard-coding your own access code into your download application framework

In admin section create a tab to register your application with facebook, which will redirect user to the `facebook.com/developer` where he/she can register their application and after registration they can put their access token back in you application framework admin section. you can store this details in some table and fetch it where ever you need it for authentication.

hope this logic helps for you.